# Googlesheet ImportXML from a Lenovopage

Tags: google-sheets

my plan is it to manage my pool by my self. For this job i will create a Google Spreadsheet with the warranty-data. When I create the Formel IMPORTXML I get always the error back "Could not fetch url:....." - When I click manuell on the URL it works. It is a very simply Google Spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q_2GJByZUvEioM5HZ6IBJaFKs5kAOfDkIJtNMrODLQM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: May not be available if js loaded as I get #n/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly that is not available by the time ImportXML has loaded info. You can write your own user defined function which you call by passing it the string cell address of the cell containing the URL.

This is based on the fact that the webpage actually contains a script which uses a JSON string containing the value of interest in it. `split` can then be used to access this value.

**Script segement:**

[image]

**Example call:**

```
=GetExpiration(CELL("address";B1))
```

[image]

---

**Code:**

```
function GetExpiration(rng) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rng);
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(range.getValue()).getContentText();
  var expiration = html.split('expirationDate":"')[1].split('"')[0];  
  return expiration;
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry for my late answert - your example is not super --> it is excelent :). Thanks very much